# Interpreting a sentence with multiple commas and "and" conjunction

Tags: commas, conjunctions

I am confused over the highlighted statement: ***and his 200,000-strong army composed of mostly Mongol soldiers at the second Battle of Ningyuan*** in the paragraph below.

> Yuan Chonghuan (6 June 1584 – 22 September 1630), courtesy name Yuansu
>   or Ziru, was a politician, military general and writer who served
>   under the Ming dynasty. Widely regarded as a patriot in Chinese
>   culture, he is best known for defending Liaoning from Jurchen invaders
>   during the Later Jin invasion of the Ming. As a general, Yuan
>   Chonghuan excelled as a cannoneer and sought to incorporate European
>   cannon designs into the Ming arsenal.
>
> Yuan's military career reached its height when he defeated the Jurchen
>   ruler, Nurhaci, and his army in the first Battle of Ningyuan. Later
>   on, Yuan also defeated Nurhaci's son and successor, Hong Taiji, ***and
>   his 200,000-strong army composed of mostly Mongol soldiers at the
>   second Battle of Ningyuan***. Yuan met his end when he was arrested
>   and executed by lingchi ("slow slicing") on the order of the Chongzhen
>   Emperor under false charges of treason, which were believed to have
>   been planted against him by the Jurchens.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuan_Chonghuan

The 200,000 soldiers belong to Nurhaci, or Nurhaci's successor, or Yuan? How should I interpret this sentence and re-write this (if needed) to give better clarity.

Comment: I am very confused by the title of this question. There is only a normal conjunction, and I certainly don't see multiple commas that could be causing confusion. In fact, the phrase in bold *has* no commas. As far as I can tell, the meaning is very straightforward: the army belongs to Hong Taiji.

Comment: It says that Yuan won the second Battle of Ningyuan. He fought Hong Taiji and *Taiji's* Mongol army.

Comment: @KannE, thank you. let me read up on this.